# When would not normalizing input values have higher accuracy?

Tags: classification, normalization, deep-learning

Right now I'm training a deep neural network for a binary classification problem, with a feature set of winrates. As such, each winrate is bigger or equal to 0 but smaller than 100.

I've been getting promising results without normalizing the input data, until I normalized it and got staggeringly worse accuracy.

The input feature is a 2d matrix of size 20, and the network has four layers with differing numbers of nodes in each layer. I'm using sgd optimizer and ReLU activation for the hidden layers, and the softmax activation function for the output layer.

The thing I'm wondering is why I'm getting better results with the neural network without the normalization? Is it because the optimal hyperparameters required for the network with the normalized input are different from when it is not normalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing I'm wondering is why I'm getting better results with the neural network without the normalization?

From a theoretical standpoint, normalizing your input shouldn't affect accuracy, in a sense that a NN can converge to any range of input values.

The reason why we normalize our data when using NNs is that it offers some useful properties, mainly regarding convergence and convergence speed. You can read more details [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/54376/34269).

> Is it because the optimal hyperparameters required for the network with the normalized input are different from when it is not normalized?

Yes, I think that is your problem. Some hyperparameters might be optimized for the regular input and might not work well for the normalized one. An example of this could be a higher learning rate, which might work for a higher range of input values but not for a normalized one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that normalizing the input data decreases the computational cost and it does not have any effects on your performance.

That being said, normalizing might help you to get better results for the same number of iterations. But that does not mean that normalizing leads to better performance. Probably, you can get the same results for the original data by more number of iterations.